# dynamic directory for external table in procedure (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am using the following Procedure in pl sql

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOAD ( file_path VARCHAR2)
    AS
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY ext_tab_data AS '''||file_path||''' ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
    CREATE TABLE DUMMY
     (
         col1      VARCHAR2(2000),
         col2     VARCHAR2(2000)
    ) 
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
       (
             TYPE oracle_loader
             DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_data
             ACCESS PARAMETERS 
             (
                   RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
                   badfile ext_tab_data:''bad_file.bad''
                   logfile ext_tab_data:''logs.log''
                    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
                   (FIELDS TERMINATED BY '','')
                   MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
                   ( 
                             col1  CHAR ,
                             col2  CHAR  

             ))
                 LOCATION (''F1.txt'')
    )REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;';
    END;

/
EXEC LOAD('C:\Users\external_table_new');
```

But this doesn't work, i'm getting this error

```
exec load
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.LOAD", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

oracle execute immediate.Can anyone help please? i want directory name to be added dynamically when the procedure is run by passing a parameter.

Comment: Creating directories dynamically seems an odd requirement. When you do `create directory ...` that directory's filepath has to be available to the server. Are you really adding/changing the directories available to the server? Typically, you would create a small number of directories (e.g. one for input files, one for output, etc, or maybe one for typeA files, another for typeB files, etc) and then move files into the relevant directory. I'm curious as to why you need to dynamically create the directories in Oracle?

Comment: Thankx for the reply boneist ..ya that's what i wanted. Is it possible in a single procedure or should i create another procedure (for directory)and call this load procedure from it ? Because i cant able to excecute both statement into a single procedure ... So do you have any solution !!

Comment: First off, don't create objects etc in the SYSTEM schema (or SYS for that matter) - you should create a new schema with which to do this. (I say this, because SYS and SYSTEM are "special" schemas, and you might get unintended side effects from developing in them.). As it stands, it looks like the issue lies in your create table statement.

Comment: And are you really, really adding/amending directories on the server prior to running this procedure? Because that sounds very, very strange and potentially a security risk.

Comment: Ya boneist ... The server will be handled by me ... Dont worry ... Just give me the solution  .. I'll be thankful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL statements should not be terminated by a semicolon.  Remove the last `;` from the `create table` statement in the execute immediate.

You might also want to look into using the alternative quoting syntax.  This will allow you to include the dynamic SQL without as much escaping.

For example:

```
execute immediate q'[
   create table dummy ...
   ...
                   badfile ext_tab_data:'bad_file.bad'
   ...
    )REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
]';
```